Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'
I am running an already-developed ASP.NET zero project in Visual Studio 2022.
Currently I get an error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AbpEditions'

when I run register.cshtml or login.cshtml.
I have searched the internet and tried to run a migration to resolve this
Update-Migration

After the build started and finished I get this error now:

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Please let me know the solution so that I can run this project. As per my project's appsettings.json, it should run on the localhost database. I can see a total of six DbContext classes in the project, two in the HealthCheck folder and three in the Entity Framework Core folder.
Please find the code below which uses the object AbpEditions which is in Home Controller,
private void CreateEditions()
{
    var defaultEdition = _context.Editions.IgnoreQueryFilters().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == EditionManager.DefaultEditionName);
    if (defaultEdition == null)
    {
        defaultEdition = new SubscribableEdition { Name = EditionManager.DefaultEditionName, DisplayName = EditionManager.DefaultEditionName };
        _context.Editions.Add(defaultEdition);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        /* Add desired features to the standard edition, if wanted... */
    }

    if (defaultEdition.Id > 0)
    {
        CreateFeatureIfNotExists(defaultEdition.Id, AppFeatures.ChatFeature, true);
        CreateFeatureIfNotExists(defaultEdition.Id, AppFeatures.TenantToTenantChatFeature, true);
        CreateFeatureIfNotExists(defaultEdition.Id, AppFeatures.TenantToHostChatFeature, true);
    }
}

private void CreateFeatureIfNotExists(int editionId, string featureName, bool isEnabled)
{
    var defaultEditionChatFeature = _context.EditionFeatureSettings.IgnoreQueryFilters()
                                                .FirstOrDefault(ef => ef.EditionId == editionId && ef.Name == featureName);

    if (defaultEditionChatFeature == null)
    {
        _context.EditionFeatureSettings.Add(new EditionFeatureSetting
        {
            Name = featureName,
            Value = isEnabled.ToString().ToLower(),
            EditionId = editionId
        });
    }
}

Please find the image below. Right now the  Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core couldn't install. After I click the install but it doesn't install.

Please find the image of the package manager console. The command is not working for adding the migration


We probably need to see some code for this. Can you include the code that uses the object name AbpEditions, and the namespace using declaration(s) that are required for it tor run/compile, for starters?

@TylerH please find  the code posted above.

do you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; installed in your project? what is your dbcontext class looks like? could you share your program.cs file? Is it possible for you to share the reproducible sample with us. delete the existing migration files and run again this command: dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate and dotnet ef database update

Sure sir, I'll just update you with a details required. @jalpa

I don't see any instance of the word or object AbpEditions or IMigrator in the code you shared. Is that really the code that is highlighted/called out by line number and file name when you encounter that error?

The only problem is that the migration doesn't run, the other exception is a mere consequence. Please focus on the migration problem in the question. What does the app  initialization look like?

@JalpaPanchal . Yes I have seen the  Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core has not been installed from the nuget package manager. It shows the Install button back. Not sure which version is to be installed 8.0.10 latest or 8.0.8

@JalpaPanchal I have just deleted the migration and once I write dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate, there is no affect. Please see the image above too,

@AmmadHassand could you share your dbcontext class code? and when you try to install the Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core did you see any errors?

could you try to run this command to clear the nuget cache dotnet nuget locals all --clear try to run this command Add-Migration InitialMigrationsand Update-Database also it would be great if you share program.cs file
